# How to call a function written in numba from C/C++

Tags: python, c, numba

According to the [numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/cfunc.html): " The numba.cfunc() decorator creates a compiled function callable from foreign C code"

Does it also mean that I can create a dll which I can call from my C code?

The example only shows how to pass the function as a callback to other C/C++ based library which is embedded into Python.

Update: 
To clarify: my goal is to embed this function in a pure C code base. (All the way up to main)

Comment: Is the C caller invoked from Python, or is it C all the way up to `main()`?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you only have a function somewhere and get a pointer to that function. There will not be any identifier for the created function if that's what you mean

Comment: This is possible using CFFI, but you will always need a Python interpreter. https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html